# How how update redux store from layout file in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

I'm building an expo-app and I manage state with `react-redux`, so my `<Provider>` in is in the top level _layout file.

My problem is I'm working with expo notification and I need to get the title, body, and some data received from the server through the notification and dispatch it to the store for later use, but when I try to dispatch I got an error that says:

> could not find react-redux context value

I realize that this error occurs because I try to use dispatch before wrapping the whole app in redux `<Provider>` but I don't know how I can do this. Below is my code.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Stack, SplashScreen } from "expo-router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistor, store } from "../src/redux/store/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import { router } from "expo-router";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addMessage } from "../src/redux/slice/system-messages";

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "(tabs)",
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

function saveNotificationResponse() {
  const dispatcher = useDispatch();
  const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response.notification.request.content.data);
      dispatcher(addMessage(response.notification.request.content.data));
    }
  );

  return () => {
    subscription.remove();
  };
}

export default function _layout() {
  useEffect(() => {
    saveNotificationResponse();
  }, []);

  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../src/assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
    DMBold: require("../src/assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf"),
    DMMedium: require("../src/assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf"),
    DMRegular: require("../src/assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf"),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="index"
            options={{
              title: "Home",
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="[missing]"
            options={{
              title: "404",
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="(tabs)"
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="order/index"
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="search/searchpage"
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </Stack>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

So when I try to run `saveNotificationResponse()` I got this error how can I fix this and still save my response to the store? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `useDispatch` from a non-React function or custom hook, e.g. it can't be called from within the `saveNotificationResponse` function.

You *can* use the `store` object to directly dispatch actions to the store.

```js
...
import { ..., store } from "../src/redux/store/store";
...

function setupNotificationListener() {
  const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
    (response) => {
      store.dispatch(addMessage(
        response.notification.request.content.data
      ));
    }
  );

  // Return the subscription so callees can unsubscribe when they need to
  return subscription;
}

...

export default function _layout() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = setupNotificationListener();

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

The alternative is to create a React component that is rendered ***under*** the Redux `Provider` component such that it can access the Redux context.

Example:

```
const NotificationListener = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
      (response) => {
        dispatch(addMessage(response.notification.request.content.data));
      }
    );

    return subscription.remove;
  }, [dispatch]);

  return null;
};
```

```
export default function _layout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    ...
  });

  ...

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <NotificationListener />
        <Stack>
          ...
        </Stack>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said your useEffect that triggers your useDispatch is outside your reducer wrapper.
You have to place your useEffect somewhere inside your `<PersistGate/>`.

You could for example create a component `HandlePushNotification` that will wrap your stack `<Stack>`

Something like that :

```
export const HandlePushNotification = ({ children }) => {
  function saveNotificationResponse() {
    const dispatcher = useDispatch();
    const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response.notification.request.content.data);
        dispatcher(addMessage(response.notification.request.content.data));
      }
    );

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    saveNotificationResponse();
  }, []);

  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

And in your initial component :

```
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <HandlePushNotification>
        <Stack>{/* {your code here} */}</Stack>
      </HandlePushNotification>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
```